# MS Project Leveling doesn't work as expected for "As Late as Possible" (ALAP) Taks

Tags: schedule, ms-project

In MS Project, the Leveling functionality doesn't seem to work as I would expect for tasks with the "As Late As Possible" constraint. It seems to try to over-allocate a resource by default to make tasks finish later than they actually *need* to finish. Instead, I want the leveling functionality to account for other tasks when deciding the start and end dates. It's ok if some of them finish well before the deadline, as long as it's "As Late As Possible", accounting for the other tasks.

Please see the this screenshot for an example:

[Leveling Error and Gantt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sygB.png)

Notice #202 is ok because no other tasks have deadlines before #202 starts. But #201, #200, and #205 conflict. Instead, I would want #200 to finish on 3/12, and #205 to finish before #200 starts (no overlap)

Is there some way I can adjust the settings to get this to work as I want it to